# IOS app freezes after didFinishWithLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm making an IOS app, and the app freezes after returning from didFinishWIthLaunchingWithOptions.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{



self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.


self.viewController = [[FooPlatformViewController alloc] init];

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

 //Set to interactive mode
[self.viewController.motionController setInteractiveMode:TRUE];
[self.viewController.motionController recoverSML];
[self.viewController.motionController startRecording];

return YES;
```

}

Checking all the variables in there leads me to believe everything went fine.  I don't see any errors or messages in the output.  However, after the function returns, the app freezes.

I've noticed several strange things about this freeze.  First, when I pause the execution during the freeze, the app has a call stack that looks like:

mach_msg_trap

mach_msg

etc

etc

main

None of my code is in there, all the way back to my single line main.

Next, this freeze only occurs in running the simulator for the iphone.  The ipad simulator works fine, as does putting the app on the phone and running that

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Post the code you have in **`didFinishWIthLaunchingWithOptions`**. You are most likely trying to access something that has been released. Are you using ARC?

Comment: Did you alter `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`? If so, can you post the code? Thanks.

Comment: I did.  I've edited my post above to display it.

Comment: Having same problem here. But this problem was reported by a user. I can't reproduce it by my side.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me, 
maybe the problem is somewhere here

```
//Set to interactive mode
[self.viewController.motionController setInteractiveMode:TRUE];
[self.viewController.motionController recoverSML];
[self.viewController.motionController startRecording];
```

I think that the default simulators in xcode doesnt support accelerometers, microphone and camera. Probably accessing any of those might cause the freeze. I remember crashing when accessing the camera on the simulator.

Although it's weird that you dont crash on iPad simulator. It's just a wild guess of mine.